# How to do a word count on a csv file based on a given columns unique values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, word-count

**I have a csv file that contains data that I would like to do a word count on based on the 'type' field values. Here is what the data inside my csv file looks like:**

```
type  |  text
type1,  random series of text
type1,  random series of text
type1,  random series of text
type2,  random series of text
type2,  random series of text
type3,  random series of text
type3,  random series of text
```

Per type, I want to do a word count and then output the results to a csv file based on the values in the type column. **The problem is that there can be multiple words in the text field
that are in another type**. For example, 'random' is in type1, type2, and type3 multiple times. I want to find out a way to do a total word count by the type.

**For example, my desired output based on the csv file above would look like:**

```
word    |count  | type

random,  3,      type1
series,  3,      type1
of,      3,      type1
text,    3,      type1
random,  2,      type2
series,  2,      type2
of,      2,      type2
text,    2,      type2
random,  2,      type3
series,  2,      type3
of,      2,      type3
text,    2,      type3
```

In my head, I want to put the data into a dataframe, then put distinct type values into a list, loop over the records in the csv file based on the type value list, and then append the word count to a new csv file.  I have started a script but I am having troubles on how to complete this code.

**Here is my script:**

```
import pandas as pd
in_file = r"data.csv"


df = pd.read_csv(in_file,encoding='latin-1' )

#Create a list of all the unique type values
type_list = df['type'].unique().tolist()


df=pd.DataFrame()

# Loop over type list and do a word count on the text column
for x in type_list:
    df.append({'word': df["text"].str.split("\s",expand=True).stack(),
    'count':df["NOTETEXT"].str.split("\s",expand=True).value_counts(),'type':x}, ignore_index=False)

# Output to csv file
df.to_csv(r'outputfile.csv')
```

Any ideas or suggestions would work as I am new to Python.

Comment: Shouldn't the counts for type2 and type3 be `2`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. View edits.

Answer (score 1):

Try [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) + [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas-dataframe-value-counts):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': {0: 'type1', 1: 'type1', 2: 'type1', 3: 'type2', 4: 'type2',
             5: 'type3', 6: 'type3'},
    'text': {0: 'random series of text', 1: 'random series of text',
             2: 'random series of text', 3: 'random series of text',
             4: 'random series of text', 5: 'random series of text',
             6: 'random series of text'}
})

df['text'] = df['text'].str.split()

df = df.explode('text').value_counts().reset_index(name='count')

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
     type    text  count
0   type1      of      3
1   type1  random      3
2   type1  series      3
3   type1    text      3
4   type2      of      2
5   type2  random      2
6   type2  series      2
7   type2    text      2
8   type3      of      2
9   type3  random      2
10  type3  series      2
11  type3    text      2
```